# Meaning of the phrasal verb "clamp down" in cotext

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

Here it goes:

> When you **clamp down** to hold your breath and tighten your trunk muscles, you create a pressure gradient between the inside and the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means:

> When you try to hold your breath[...]

In other words, "when you attempt or make an effort to hold your breath[...]".


[The Oxford Learners' Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clamp-down)

> to take strict action in order to prevent something, especially crime.

Based on this, I would assume that it roughly means the same thing.